# Use of an offline HTML file instead of a URL in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

How can I convert this code so it uses an offline (bundled) file instead of the `"http://5times9.com"`?

```
- (void)loadAddWeb {
UIWebView *addWeb = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://5times9.com"];
NSURLRequest *webURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];
[addWeb loadRequest:webURLRequest];
[addWeb setScalesPageToFit:NO];
[addWeb setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)];
[self addSubview:addWeb];}
```

Comment: This isn't "Xcode code", it's Objective-C. That you happen to be using Xcode to manage it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By an offline file, I assume you mean a file you will put in the bundle aforehand. In which case everything is clearly explained here: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle

Lucky you: your problem is solved in this as:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"offline5times9.com" ofType:@"htm"];  
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
if (htmlData) {  
    [webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kheldar.kikoo"]];  
}
```

If you want to update the HTML file from Internet at some point, you can store a version in Documents, as stated in the comments of the link.

Comment: @Val: "Can you just do it for me" earns you a very bad reputation in software developer communities. The best thing you could do for yourself is to read this carefully: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html